# Python type 'exceptions.ValueError' - unsupported format character

Tags: python, format

Can anyone help me figure out whats wrong with my code? I suppose its some kind of character substitution thingy but i can´t figure out what.

```
def diagnose(*arg, **kwargs):
import cx_Oracle
import traceback
try:
    def ativa_dbms():
        while True:
            lineVar = cursor.var(cx_Oracle.STRING)
            statusVar = cursor.var(cx_Oracle.NUMBER)
            cursor.callproc("dbms_output.get_line", (lineVar, statusVar))
            if statusVar.getvalue() != 0:
             break
            print lineVar.getvalue()

    query_diag="""
                declare
                  vContrato  sn_contrato.num_contrato%type := :P_CONTRATO;
                  vCid       sn_contrato.cid_contrato%type := :P_CID_CONTRATO;
                  vPonto     sn_rel_ponto_produto.id_ponto%type := :P_ID_PONTO;
                  vCont      number := 0;
                  vStatus    number := 0;
                  vTpProduto number := 0;

                begin

                  select count(id_caracteristica)
                    into vTpProduto
                    from sn_rel_ponto_produto a, sn_produto b
                   where a.id_produto = b.id_produto
                     and a.num_contrato = vContrato
                     and a.cid_contrato = vCid
                     and a.id_ponto = vPonto
                     and a.dt_fim > sysdate
                     and b.id_caracteristica = 4;

                    dbms_output.put_line('Qtd produto netfone no ponto: '||vTpProduto);

                  if vTpProduto = 4 then
                    select count(*)
                      into vCont
                      from sn_telefone_voip
                     where id_ponto = vPonto
                       and num_contrato = vContrato
                       and cid_contrato = vCid;

                    if vCont = 0 then
                      dbms_output.put_line('Ponto nao possui linhas na sn_telefone_voip');
                      vStatus := 1;
                    end if;

                  end if;
                  select vStatus into :p_status from dual;

                end;
              """

    con = arg[0]
    cursor = con.cursor()
    kwargs['P_STATUS'] = cursor.var(cx_Oracle.NUMBER)

    print 'Iniciando diagnostico...'
    #cursor.callproc("dbms_output.enable")
    cursor.execute(query_diag, kwargs)
    #ativa_dbms()
    status = kwargs['P_STATUS'].getvalue()
    cursor.close()
    con.close()
    return status, kwargs
except traceback, tb:
    print traceback.tb_lineno(tb)
```

**Error
     - unsupported format character 't' (0x74) at     index 87**

Solved by putting %% instead of % on the characters in 'query_diag'

Comment: I don't think it likes the `%type`s, but you've given so little (no?) explanation as to what is going on here, much less what you want it to do, I can't say much more than that.

Comment: Encoding errors ! Before put data encode it.

Comment: The error is the bold line at the bottom of the page.
Error - unsupported format character 't' (0x74) at index 87

Comment: My guess: the error is from `cursor.execute(query_diag, kwargs)`. read the [cx_Oracle doc](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cursor.html)

Comment: Please don't do this: `print traceback.tb_lineno(tb)`.  Just don't catch the exception in the first place.  The error message is much more useful that way.

Comment: Cool Kevin, thanks. Its just i dont have access to the actual console to see the traceback msg so i was trying to figure out what line it was.